# Creating a hash with keys and values selected from between points in a string

Tags: regex, perl, data-structures, hash, bioinformatics

I get the following result from my code below.

For example, with `$seq` set to `aaaGACGTCaaaGAATTCaaaGACGTCaaa`:

```
 RE: AatII
 GACGTC found at 4-9
 GACGTC found at 22-27
 RE: EcoRI
 GACGTC found at 4-9
 GACGTC found at 22-27
 GAATTC found at 13-18
```

While this is pretty close to what I want to achieve, what I really want to do is use a list of "reference enzymes" - which I store as hash keys (in the example below `AatII` and `EcoRI` in `%RE`) - in order to find the best cut site in the `$seq` sequence string and the store the results in a data-structure such as a hash.

The cut site selection is done according to an associated "enzyme string" value for each reference enzyme key in the hash. In the code below the key `AatII` is set to value `GACGTC 5`; it will cut `GACGTC` after the fifth position: (`GACGT|C`) ; whereas `EcoRI => GAATTC 1` splits the sequence `GAATTC` after the first position (`G|AATTC`) . So, for each enzyme key in my hash I find a site in the sequence `$seq` based on that key's associated string and a "cut site" from the number associated with that string in the key's hash value. The number refers to the position of the cut after position "1" of the enzyme string.

For the sequence `$seq` the results would be:  `(aaaGACGT)(CaaaG)(AATTCaaaGACGT)(Caaa)` (here brackets are used to show cut points). The positions of the cut sites in the string would be as follows:

```
                0------8 9---13 14----------26 27--30
```

This is based on a run of the script using both `EcoRI` and `AatII` to select enzyme sequences and cut the full sequence leaving:  `aaaGACGT    CaaaG    AATTCaaaGACGT    Caaa`

I would like my script to store results of each run in a hash with keys/values such as `{0=>8, 9=>13, 14=>26, 27=>30}`.  By using `sort` on my keys and values ***after each iteration***; then using a binary search to find the closest previous cutsite and adding "1" to be the value of `$end` in the current iteration there should be as many entries in the hash as there are cutsites.

I do not know if this is possible. If it is, can someone point me in the right direction as to how to Can anyone help me transform my code in order to approach this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %RE =( 'AatII' => 'GACGTC 5', 'EcoRI' => 'GAATTC 1' );
my $input='';
my @matches =();
my @enz = keys %RE;
my @value = values %RE;
print "Seq:";
my $seq = <STDIN>;
chomp $seq;
print "OK \n";
while ($input ne 'quit') {
    print "RE:";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;
    foreach (@enz) {
        if ($input =~ /$_/) {
            #print "Key:", $_," Value:", $RE{$_};
            my @seqval = $seq;
            my $val = $RE{$_};
            my $real = substr($val, 0, -2);
            #my $cut = substr($val, 0, (length($val)-3));
            my $cut = chop $val;
            my $length = length ($real);
            my $mew = substr ($real, 0, $cut);
            my $two = substr ($real, -1, ($length-$cut));            
            #my $push = push @valval;
            #chomp %RE{$_};
            while ($seq =~ /($real)/g) {
                my $match = $1;
                #print "$match", "\n";
                my $length = length($&);
                #print "$length", "\n";
                my $pos = length($`);
                #print "$pos", "\n";
                my $start = $pos + 1;
                #print "$start", "\n";
                my $end = $pos + $length;
                #print "$end", "\n";
                my $hitpos = "$start-$end";
                #print "$hitpos", "\n";
                push @matches, "$match found at $hitpos ";
                #print "\tfound:", "\n","\n";
                #print "\t\t\t$1$mew", "\n";
                #print "\t\t\t$two$3", "\n";
                #print "next restriction enzyme:","\n";
            } print "$_\n" foreach @matches;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good starting point: http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: You can't sort a hashes keys. You are going to need an array.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to have in your results: do you want a hash with `key` `0` and `value` `8` (`{0=>8,...}` etc.)?

Comment: You might find [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) (available as short cut `use DDP ;`) useful for exploring the data structures you create.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Khuram and welcome to Stackoverflow :-)

It seems you may have dropped your question but I'm adding this answer to make it more complete and potentially useful to others who find it. As @mappec suggested, you should consult the [Bioperl](http://www.bioperl.org) website where you may find more resources.

While there may be simpler ways of doing this, I like your idea of creating a hash to store the cut sites is a good one because it leverages one of the powers of perl: the ability to create arbitrarily complex data structures on the fly.  That said, it can sometimes be complicated to get your data back out! **:-)**

As @user1937198 notes, hashes are *unordered*, so if you want your output to preserve the order/positions of the enzyme strings in your sequence you'll not only have to sort your hash by its keys, you'll have create sortable keys to start with.  In your question your sample output shows `found at 4-9`, `... 22-27`, and  `... 13-18` out of order because you don't have a datastructure you have `sort`ed.  Fixing that part is not too hard. To prove it, here's your script with some of the print statements removed and with the `$seq` sequence string processed into a [`HoH`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES)(*hash of hashes*) called `%cuttings` that is sorted by its keys (but remember, the order is not *preserved*):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %RE =( 'AatII' => 'GACGTC 5', 'EcoRI' => 'GAATTC 1' );
my %cuttings = ();
my $input='';
my @enz = keys %RE;
print "Seq:";
my $seq = "aaaGACGTCaaaGAATTCaaaGACGTCaaa";
chomp $seq;
print "OK \n";
while ($input ne 'quit') {
    print "RE:";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;
    foreach (@enz) {
        if ($input =~ /$_/) {
            my @seqval = $seq;
            my $val = $RE{$_};
            my $real = substr($val, 0, -2);
            my $cut = chop $val;
            my $cutsite = 0 ;
            my $length = length ($real);
            my $mew = substr ($real, 0, $cut);
            my $two = substr ($real, -1, ($length-$cut));            
            while ($seq =~ /($real)/g) {
               my $match = $1;
               my $length = length($&);
               my $pos = length($`); #`fix SO syntax highlighting :)
               my $start = $pos + 1;
               my $end = $pos + $length;
               my $hitpos = "$start..$end";
               my $cutsite = $end ;
               ${$cuttings{ $cutsite }}{ $input } = "$match at $hitpos ";
            }
          }
        }

  foreach my $cutsite (sort { $a <=> $b} keys %cuttings) {
      print " $cuttings{$cutsite}{$_}\n" for ( keys %{ $cuttings{$cutsite} } );
   }
}
```

The output would be:

```
$ ~/tmp/ perl biogenetic.pl
Seq:OK 
RE:EcoRI
 GAATTC found at 13..18   
RE:AatII
 GACGTC found at 4..9   
 GAATTC found at 13..18   
 GACGTC found at 22..27   
RE:quit
```

The `AatII` enzyme cut sites are sorted correctly "around" the first `EcoRI` reference enzyme. If you want to see what the has looks like as you go along you could use `Data::Dumper` or `Data::Printer` (also known as `DDP`) to dump the hash when the program exits in an `END` block:

```
 END {
    use DDP;
   p %cuttings ;                              
 }
```

That would show the following:

```
{
    9    {
        AatII   "GACGTC found at 4..9 "
    },
    18   {
        EcoRI   "GAATTC found at 13..18 "
    },
    27   {
        AatII   "GACGTC found at 22..27 "
    }
}
```

**NB**: I've just reused your code to do this so you were most of the way there as it was. I'm not a geneticist so there may still be issues if enzyme strings do things like overlap (do they do that?).  There are a lot of variable names to keep track of in your code and there's probably a way to refactor things to be bit simpler or more elegant - which I leave as an exercise for you and other contributors :-)  If you use perl frequently you get good at it very quickly.

HTH. Good luck with your project.